# How to split a date column into separate day , month ,year column in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataset `df`:

```
               Dewptm   Fog  Humidity   Pressurem     Tempm      Wspdm  Rainfall
datetime_utc                            
1996-11-01    11.666667 0.0  52.916667  -2659.666667  22.333333  2.466667   0
1996-11-02    10.458333 0.0  48.625000  1009.833333   22.916667  8.028571   0
1996-11-03    12.041667 0.0  55.958333  1010.500000   21.791667  4.804545   0
1996-11-04    10.222222 0.0  48.055556  1011.333333   22.722222  1.964706   0
...
```

Here is `df.columns`:

```
Index(['Dewptm', 'Fog', 'Humidity', 'Pressurem', 'Rain', 'Tempm', 'Wspdm',
       'Rainfall'],
      dtype='object')
```

How could I split `datetime_utc` column into the year, month and day column?

I tried:

```py
df["day"] = df['datetime_utc'].map(lambda x: x.day)
df["month"] = df['datetime_utc'].map(lambda x: x.month)
df["year"] = df['datetime_utc'].map(lambda x: x.year)
```

Error:

```
KeyError: 'datetime_utc'
```

Also

```py
pd.concat([df.drop('datetime_utc', axis = 1), 
          (df.datetime_utc.str.split("-).str[:3].apply(pd.Series)
          .rename(columns={0:'year', 1:'month', 2:'day'}))], axis = 1)
```

I am getting error:

```
KeyError: "['datetime_utc'] not found in axis"
```

The problem I am facing is the column `datetime_utc` is the default index column in my dataset.

Comment: looks like it's the index not a column

Comment: The issue is not *"How to split a date column..."*, it's *"How to split a date index"*.

Comment: One-liner: `df = df.assign(year=df.index.year, month=df.index.month, day=df.index.day)`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The problem is that `datetime_utc` is in your index instead a column, so you have to access your index to be able to make your new columns:

```
df['day'] = df.index.day
df['month'] = df.index.month
df['year'] = df.index.year

print(df)
                 Dewptm  Fog   Humidity    Pressurem      Tempm     Wspdm  \
datetime_utc                                                                
1996-11-01    11.666667  0.0  52.916667 -2659.666667  22.333333  2.466667   
1996-11-02    10.458333  0.0  48.625000  1009.833333  22.916667  8.028571   
1996-11-03    12.041667  0.0  55.958333  1010.500000  21.791667  4.804545   
1996-11-04    10.222222  0.0  48.055556  1011.333333  22.722222  1.964706   

              Rainfall  day  month  year  
datetime_utc                              
1996-11-01           0    1     11  1996  
1996-11-02           0    2     11  1996  
1996-11-03           0    3     11  1996  
1996-11-04           0    4     11  1996
```

If you want `datetime_utc` as a column you have to reset your index and then you can access the datetime methods with `dt.month`, `dt.year` and `dt.day` like following:

```
# Reset our index so datetime_utc becomes a column
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

# Create new columns
df['day'] = df['datetime_utc'].dt.day
df['month'] = df['datetime_utc'].dt.month
df['year'] = df['datetime_utc'].dt.year

print(df)
  datetime_utc     Dewptm  Fog   Humidity    Pressurem      Tempm     Wspdm  \
0   1996-11-01  11.666667  0.0  52.916667 -2659.666667  22.333333  2.466667   
1   1996-11-02  10.458333  0.0  48.625000  1009.833333  22.916667  8.028571   
2   1996-11-03  12.041667  0.0  55.958333  1010.500000  21.791667  4.804545   
3   1996-11-04  10.222222  0.0  48.055556  1011.333333  22.722222  1.964706   

   Rainfall  day  month  year  
0         0    1     11  1996  
1         0    2     11  1996  
2         0    3     11  1996  
3         0    4     11  1996
```

**Note** if your index is not in `datetime` type yet, use the following before you try to extract year, month and day:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner version is to call [`timetuple()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.timetuple.html) on each Timestamps, which returns a tuple similar to `datetime.datetime.timetuple`. Since only year, month, day are needed, slice the first 3 elements.

```py
# if datetime_utc is index
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)           # <-- omit if index is already datetime64[ns]
df[['year', 'month', 'day']] = [x.timetuple()[:3] for x in df.index.tolist()]


# if datetime_utc is a column
df['datetime_utc'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime_utc'])  # <-- omit if datetime_utc is already datetime64[ns]
df[['year', 'month', 'day']] = df['datetime_utc'].apply(lambda x: x.timetuple()[:3]).tolist()
```