# How to split a date index into separate day , month ,year column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataset `df1`:

[image: My Table]

I did a column and index transpose previously:

```
df1 = df.T
```

The dataset `df` previously looked like this:

[image]

I have already use the `.to_datetime` function to convert my dates:

```
df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.index).strftime('%Y-%m')
```

How could I split my date index and add them to new 'year' and 'month' columns on the right of the table?

I tried:

```
df1['month'] = df.index.month
df1['year'] = df.index.year
```

However, it is returning me the following error:

> AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'day'

This is actually a follow up to another question raised before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55776571/how-to-split-a-date-column-into-separate-day-month-year-column-in-pandas/55776634)

I wasn't able to add comment over there as I am a new account holder to stack overflow.

Thank you everyone, I am a new learner so please bear with me.

Comment: What do you mean by spliting? what would your desired output look like?

Comment: I can't understand what *`'Variables'` is actually an index name when I call for `df.columns`* means? It's just the index. No need to confuse us by mentioning transpose.

Comment: @mephisto: from both the OP's original question, and what they wrote above, they want to **extract separate year, month and day columns from the (datetime) index**, so they can `pd.concat` them into some new dataframe.

Comment: @smci hi yup you are right. I would like to create columns of 'year' and 'month' at the right of the table so that I can group them accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dates are index then your code should have worked. However, if the dates are in date column then try:

```
df['day'] = df.date.dt.day
df['month'] = df.date.dt.month
df['year'] = df.date.dt.year
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this too and ended up with this error:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'date'

:(

Comment: then you dont have a date column. You can create a column first with:
df['date'] = df.index
Then you can try the codes I gave in answer

Comment: I think I got it! Wow, I was stuck at this for hours. I think I am able to continue forward now. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df['day'] = df.index.day
df['month'] = df.index.month
df['year'] = df.index.year
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import calendar as cal
import locale

df.Dates = pd.to_datetime(df.Dates)

df['Year'] = df.Dates.dt.year
df['Month'] = df.Dates.dt.month_name()
df['Day'] = df.Dates.dt.day
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
    df['Which Day'] = df['time'].dt.day_name()
    df['Year'] = df['time'].dt.year
    df['Month'] = df['time'].dt.month_name())
```

Comment: If you can add a link to the documentation this would be a more useful answer for anyone who finds this answer in the future :)