# Splitting the Month-Year format into seperate columns in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, string

[Snippet of Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNrLy.png)

In this dataset, how can I split the first column **Month-Year** into two seperate columns "Month" & "Year"?

- I tried using the split function but got **Series has no split*** error.

Comment: Try `.str.split`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a date column into separate day , month ,year column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55776571/how-to-split-a-date-column-into-separate-day-month-year-column-in-pandas)

Comment: what you have tried so far and don't use image

Comment: What data type is your first column? String or datetime? You can check this by using `type( data.loc[0,"Month-Year"] )`

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
    import pandas as pd

    # load your dataset
    df = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv")
    # create a new column "Month" from the first column "Month-Year" by 
    # splitting on the "," character
    df["Month"] = df["Month-Year"].str.split(",").str[0]
    # create a new column "Year" from the first column "Month-Year" by splitting 
    # on the "," character
    df["Year"] = df["Month-Year"].str.split(",").str[1]
    # drop the first column "Month-Year"
    df.drop("Month-Year", axis=1, inplace=True)
    # save the modified dataset
    df.to_csv("your_modified_dataset.csv", index=False)
```